# Why do .exe files have repeated symbols?

Tags: c, assembly, hex, exe

I made a simple c program-

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        int main() {
            printf("Hello World");
            return 0;
        }
```

on converting it into a .exe file and opening it into a text editor, i get a file with lots of repeated symbols
[image: Snippet of .exe file]

In order to better visualize it I converted it to HEX
[image: Snippet of .exe in HEX]

My question is, why are so many character repeated or 'empty'?
Is there any compression taking place behind the scenes?

Comment: Randomly looking at binary data is not productive. The way to understand what is in the file is to find and read the specs for the format of the file and tools to dump the data into decoded text representation.

Comment: My question is why does an `.exe` file have an ELF header and an ELF interpreter `ld-linux.so.2`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have created a Linux PIE executable instead of a Windows `.exe`.

Comment: What your looking at is explained quite well here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Comment: @xiver77 I made the .exe using windows subsystem for linux, perhaps that's why it is different from [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corkami/pics/master/binary/pe101/pe101.png) reference image

Comment: @Saphereye Yes, you effectively created a Linux executable in ELF format.

Comment: WSL executables are Linux ELF executables so obviously they're not EXE and don't need `.exe` extension, and can't run directly in Windows